# ¿Dentro de Docker, Cómo agregar correctamente un task a cron de forma programática (scripting)? no se perciben errores en log

Tags: docker, docker-compose, cron, crontab, contenedores

Despues de varios dias trasteando con Docker no he dado con una solucion a mi problema.

En resumidas he intenatdo meterle `cron` a `php:8.1-apache-bullseye` y pasarle un archivo con el task que quiero que ejecute el servicio cron:

contenido de `cron-task`:

```
* * * * * /var/www/html/Asset/resource/cron/cron.sh >> /var/log/cron/cron.log 2>&1
```

contenido de `cron.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Obtener la hora actual
current_time=$(date +"%H:%M:%S")

# Mensaje de advertencia
message="warning: Hello, world!!"

# Imprimir la hora y el mensaje en la salida estándar
echo "${current_time}: ${message}"
```

Para levantar todo tengo una seccion de mi docker-compose.yml en donde levanto un servicio webserver de la siguiente forma:

```
  webserver:
    env_file:
      - .env
    container_name: ${LH_SYSTEM_NAME}-Web-Server
    build:
      context: ./bin/${LH_PHP_ENVIRONMENT}
    restart: always
    networks:
      - lamp-network
    depends_on:
      - database
    volumes:
      - ${LH_PROJECT_ROOT}:/var/www/html:rw
      - ${LH_PROJECT_ROOT}${LH_DOCUMENT_ROOT-./public}:/var/www/html/public:rw
      - ${LH_VHOSTS_DIR}:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled
      - ${LH_PHP_INI}:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
      - ${LH_CRON}:/etc/script/cron-task
      - ${LH_LOG_CRON}:/var/log/cron
      - ${LH_LOG_DIR}:/var/log/apache2
    environment:
      LH_WEB_MASTER: ${LH_WEB_MASTER}
      VIRTUAL_HOST: ${LH_WEB_SERVER_DOMAIN}
      LH_APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT: ${LH_APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT}
      LH_DOCUMENT_ROOT: ${LH_DOCUMENT_ROOT}
      HOST_MACHINE_MYSQL_PORT: ${LH_HOST_MACHINE_MYSQL_PORT}
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${LH_MYSQL_DATABASE}
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${LH_MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_USER: ${LH_MYSQL_USER}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${LH_MYSQL_PASSWORD}
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
    command: [ "/bin/sh", "-c", "chmod +x /var/www/html/Asset/resource/cron/cron.sh && cp /etc/script/cron-task /etc/cron.d/cron-task && chmod 0644 /etc/cron.d/cron-task && crontab /etc/cron.d/cron-task && cron -f && service cron restart" ]
```

**Nota:** Podemos ignorar las Variables de Entorno ya que todas fueron probadas y verificadas una a una y hacen lo que se espera que hagan...

Adicional estoy implementando la sección de `command` a ver si así soluciono los problemas, pero por lo que he visto y hecho pruebas no sirve tampoco.

Comandos que se ejecutan en command:

```
chmod +x /var/www/html/Asset/resource/cron/cron.sh
cp /etc/script/cron-task /etc/cron.d/cron-task
chmod 0644 /etc/cron.d/cron-task
crontab /etc/cron.d/cron-task
cron -f
service cron restart
```

para que el archivo dentro del contenedor quede ubicado correctamente... todo esto funciona bien, incluso los comando ejecutados en command no he tenido interrupcion o mensajes de errores en la construccion y puesta en marcha de los contenedores.

Entonces mi Dockerfile contiene lo siguiente:

```
FROM php:8.1-apache-bullseye

ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

RUN a2enmod rewrite headers

RUN service apache2 restart

RUN apt-get update &&  \
    apt-get upgrade -y --no-install-recommends --fix-missing

RUN apt-get install -y cron nano wget dialog build-essential git curl zip openssl --no-install-recommends --fix-missing

RUN apt-get -y autoremove && \
    apt-get clean

ENV VISUAL=nano
ENV EDITOR=nano

RUN service cron start

RUN rm -rf /usr/src/* && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN update-rc.d cron enable
```

Esto tampoco me arroja ningun problema... ahora me voy a la terminal de mi contenedor webserver, y a pesar de que luego valido con:

```
service cron status
```

y el output dice que se esta ejecutando...

Aptura del contenido de `crontab -e`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al final el problema es que nunca ocurre nada automaticamente ... como si el servicio cron estuviera detenido...

por si acaso hice pruebas de ejecucion sobre el archivo .sh y todo funciona bien desde la terminal.

incluso agregar el registro al log... pero cuando espero que lo haga el servicio cron no pasa nada... y ya no se que hacer o donde buscar...

***Update:***

la salida de: `ps aux | grep cron`

**fue:**

```
root         1  0.0  0.0   2480   516 ?        Ss   21:46   0:00 /bin/sh -c chmod +x /var/www/html/Asset/resource/cron/cron.sh && cp /etc/script/cron-task /etc/cron.d/cron-task && chmod 0644 /etc/cron.d/cron-task && crontab /etc/cron.d/cron-task && cron -f && service cron restart
root        11  0.0  0.0   3744  2444 ?        S    21:46   0:00 cron -f
root        78  0.0  0.0   3240   712 pts/0    S+   22:11   0:00 grep cron
```

por lo que parece que a pesar de todo lo que e intentado la tarea no esta en el cron ... sigo sin saber que hacer ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Después de probar diferentes formas de manipular los archivos y crear las necesidades en un orden apropiado para integrar la utilidad cron en un contenedor y mantenerla funcionando, esto era necesario:

1. Elimine el `command` y algunos parámetros/sección de `volumenes` de mi archivo `docker-compose.yml`. Ahora se ve así:

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  reverse-proxy:
    env_file:
      - .env
    container_name: Proxy-Server
    image: jwilder/nginx-proxy
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
    ports:
      - "${LH_HOST_MACHINE_UNSECURE_HOST_PORT}:80"
    depends_on:
      - webserver
      - phpmyadmin
    networks:
      - lamp-network
    extra_hosts:
      - "${LH_WEB_SERVER_DOMAIN}:127.0.0.1"
      - "${LH_PHPMYADMIN_DOMAIN}:127.0.0.1"
      - "${LH_CRON_DOMAIN}:127.0.0.1"
      - "${LH_INCRON_DOMAIN}:127.0.0.1"
  webserver:
    env_file:
      - .env
    container_name: ${LH_SYSTEM_NAME}-Web-Server
    build:
      context: ./bin/${LH_PHP_ENVIRONMENT}
    restart: always
    networks:
      - lamp-network
    depends_on:
      - database
    volumes:
      - ${LH_PROJECT_ROOT}:/var/www/html:rw
      - ${LH_PROJECT_ROOT}${LH_DOCUMENT_ROOT}:/var/www/html/public:rw
      - ${LH_VHOSTS_DIR}:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled
      - ${LH_PHP_INI}:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
      - ${LH_LOG_DIR}:/var/log/apache2
      - ${LH_LOG_CRON}:/var/log/cron
    environment:
      LH_WEB_MASTER: ${LH_WEB_MASTER}
      VIRTUAL_HOST: ${LH_WEB_SERVER_DOMAIN}
      LH_APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT: ${LH_APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT}
      LH_DOCUMENT_ROOT: ${LH_DOCUMENT_ROOT}
      HOST_MACHINE_MYSQL_PORT: ${LH_HOST_MACHINE_MYSQL_PORT}
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${LH_MYSQL_DATABASE}
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${LH_MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_USER: ${LH_MYSQL_USER}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${LH_MYSQL_PASSWORD}
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
  database:
    env_file:
      - .env
    build:
      context: ./bin/${LH_DATABASE}
    container_name: ${LH_SYSTEM_NAME}-${LH_DATABASE}
    restart: always
    networks:
      - lamp-network
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:${LH_HOST_MACHINE_MYSQL_PORT}:${LH_HOST_MACHINE_MYSQL_PORT}"
    volumes:
      - ${LH_MYSQL_INITDB_DIR}:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
      - ${LH_MYSQL_DATA_DIR}:/var/lib/mysql
      - ${LH_MYSQL_LOG_DIR}:/var/log/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${LH_MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${LH_MYSQL_DATABASE}
      MYSQL_USER: ${LH_MYSQL_USER}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${LH_MYSQL_PASSWORD}
  phpmyadmin:
    env_file:
      - .env
    container_name: ${LH_SYSTEM_NAME}-phpmyadmin
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - database
    environment:
      VIRTUAL_HOST: ${LH_PHPMYADMIN_DOMAIN}
      PMA_HOST: database
      PMA_PORT: 3306
      PMA_USER: root
      PMA_PASSWORD: ${LH_MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${LH_MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_USER: ${LH_MYSQL_USER}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${LH_MYSQL_PASSWORD}
      UPLOAD_LIMIT: ${LH_UPLOAD_LIMIT}
      MEMORY_LIMIT: ${LH_MEMORY_LIMIT}
    volumes:
      - /sessions
      - ${LH_PHP_INI}:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/php-phpmyadmin.ini
    networks:
      - lamp-network
networks:
  lamp-network:
    driver: bridge
```

2. Cambié las secuencias de comandos en mi Dockerfile con otro enfoque:

```
FROM php:8.1-apache-bullseye

ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

RUN a2enmod rewrite headers

RUN service apache2 restart

RUN apt-get update &&  \
    apt-get upgrade -y --no-install-recommends --fix-missing

RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends --fix-missing tzdata sed build-essential dialog nano apt-utils cron wget git curl zip openssl

RUN apt-get -y autoremove && \
    apt-get clean

RUN rm -rf /usr/src/* && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN mkdir -p /var/log/cron && \
    chmod 755 /var/log/cron && \
    touch /var/log/cron/cron.log

RUN echo "* * * * * root /var/www/html/Asset/resource/cron/cron.sh >> /var/log/cron/cron.log 2>&1" > /etc/cron.d/cron-task && \
    chmod 0644 /etc/cron.d/cron-task

CMD cron && /usr/local/bin/apache2-foreground && chmod +x /var/www/html/Asset/resource/cron/cron.sh && tail -f /var/log/cron/cron.log
```

Lo más importante fue la implementación de CMD para solucionar casi todos los problemas detectados y crear los archivos desde Dockerfile en lugar de montarlos.

No estoy seguro de si es el camino correcto o la mejor forma de hacerlo, pero realmente ha sido la unica forma de dejarlo andando.

***notas adicionales:***

- Es importante incorporar al inicio del `CMD` el punto de entrada o que implementa la imagen, ya que el usar el `CMD` sustituye el `CMD` por defecto provocando problemas.
- También es importan que si se implementara `tail`... se haga al final ya que esto suele bloquear el script y la ejecución.